# Won Strunk & white badge but not listed in my badge list

Tags: bug, edits, badges

After 80 edits, I got the status in my activity page, that I have won the "Strunk & White" badge. Even when I track my badges from "Choose which badge to track" option, it still shows that I already won it. Please check out the image below.

[image]

But when I looked at my list of badges, there is no "Strunk & White" badge. And the count for silver badges still showing 10, not 11. See the image below:

[image]

Comment: How long did you wait until you did your 80th edit? It takes some time until everything is updated properly. Maybe you just have to be a bit patient ;)

Comment: While we're at it - I had a quick look at your recent edits. Things like "Please suggest a solution" are considered noise. They should be removed from posts, not added to them. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333) for the relevant discussion on MSE.

Comment: You seem to have it now: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3181136/nayana-das?tab=badges

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give it a little time.

The badges are awarded by scripts. These scripts run periodically.

You should have the badge in your profile in a few hours; or maybe a day.
If it takes longer than that, then there may indeed be a problem.

Comment: yes you are right, i got that badge just now.

Comment: Agreed, patience is required for this one. Most badges do get awarded pretty quickly (<30 minutes) but the S&W badge takes a while to come through.